# How to get a list of pull requests between 2 commits

Tags: git, github, github-api, atlassian-sourcetree

I want to make a tool that retrieves all the pull requests (title and body) done between 2 commits in SourceTree. What I have is the hash of 2 commits. I am able to get every commit hash inbetween with a single git log. I can call Github's API and list all pull requests of the repository but, from there I have a problem.

The two ways of doing seem to be by matching a range of dates or by parsing the commits associated with the pull request and see if they match but that doesn't seem like a clean solution.

Does anyone know of a way to accomplish this?
Thank you.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "two commit"? Heads of target and source branches?

Comment: How do you define if a pull request is "between" two commits? The time of creation of the pull request? Pull request's "base" commit being between the two commits?

Comment: Someone seems to have written a [script](https://gist.github.com/ryangribble/c91ea7ca54cff6907a5c2cb8025f3579) for this.

Answer (score 14):

You can get the PR numbers, by using the git log command plus grep (if grep is available to you).

```
git log --oneline commit1...commit2 | grep 'Merge pull request #'
```

Keep in mind that you can replace commit1 and commit2 with an actual tag or release.

If you want to get the title and body, you will have to extract the number from the above and then call the github API `GET /repos/:owner/:repo/pulls/:number` (see https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/)

To find total count of PRs run:

```
git log --oneline commit1...commit2 | grep 'Merge pull request #' | wc -l
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for squashed or rebased PRs.

Comment: You can also use the gh api to extract the raw delta info via https://docs.github.com/en/rest/commits/commits#compare-two-commits

Answer (score 0):

I would look into the official github cli tool.

https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_list

With this you can lists PRs. if it is sufficient to search between dates instead of commits you can easily get all merged PRs between two dates like this:

`gh pr list --base main --search "merged:2023-03-10..2023-03-15" --limit 100`