# pull requests between two tags in git

Tags: git, github, azure-devops, devops, azure-git-deployment

Is there a way to get pull requests between two tags on a specific branch.

Right now, I am using git log to do this. But, seems like this is bringing pull requests created before the first tag(PreviousVersion).

```
git log --grep 'Merged PR' --oneline $CurrentVersion...$PreviousVersion --pretty=format:\"%s\"|cut -d':' -f 1|cut -d' ' -f3
```

Can you help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a list of pull requests between 2 commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41079634/how-to-get-a-list-of-pull-requests-between-2-commits)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$CurrentVersion...$PreviousVersion` does not mean "between these two commits". It means "any commits reachable by ONLY $CurrentVersion or ONLY $PreviousVersion" so you might get some commits before $PreviousVersion.

> r1...r2 is called symmetric difference of r1 and r2 and is
> defined as r1 r2 --not $(git merge-base --all r1 r2). It is the set of commits
> that are reachable from either one of r1 (left side) or r2 (right side) but not
> from both.

Instead, use `$PreviousVersion..$CurrentVersion` (two dots). This also isn't quite "between these two commits" because Git history is not linear. It means "commits reachable by $CurrentVersion and not reachable by $PreviousVersion" which is usually what you want.

Using this [little example repository](https://gist.github.com/schwern/e705778f60a4ae2ac53101ad55dd9904)...

```
A
|
B  [current]
|
C
|
|  1 [previous]
|  |
|  2
| /
D
|
E
```

- current can see B, C, D, E.
- previous can see 1, 2, D, E.

`current...previous` will show B, C (only reachable by current) and 1, 2 (only reachable by previous).

`previous..current` will show only B and C.

`current..previous` will show only 1 and 2.

See [Revision Selection in Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection) for examples.

Comment: is there a way to do common PR's(D,E) on Previous and Current, and remove them from current. So that, we can end up with B,C.

Comment: @Ras `previous..current` will give you only B, C. Perhaps I don't understand?

Comment: It's giving me A to E.

Comment: @Ras Then your history is different. Check with `git log --oneline --all --graph --decorate`. Here's [a little script to make the example repository](https://gist.github.com/schwern/e705778f60a4ae2ac53101ad55dd9904).

Comment: Thanks @Schwern. I feel like something is wrong. Checking with our IT team, will post as soon as I hear back from them.

Comment: Hi @Schwern,Found the issue. Issue is not with tags or commands. Seems like same work item has been used in multiple PR's and that caused the issue, old work items are also appearing in hostory due to change in them. Silly one. I should delete this post or I should close it as "No Problem Found". Thanks for your help.