# Github: list PRs between two tags

Tags: git, github

Github provides a nice way to list commits between two tags, e.g. https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/compare/6.0.6...6.0.7

Is there any way to list merged PRs between two tags? I want this to include PRs that were rebase-merged.

Comment: In git or github?

Comment: @evolutionxbox as far as I know, PRs are a GitHub feature, so the question only applies to GitHub.

Comment: PRs may be a github feature, but you're asking for merged PRs which are merges with commit messages containing something like "Merge PR #546".

Comment: I don't think that's possible, check here for the available options https://docs.github.com/en/github/searching-for-information-on-github/searching-issues-and-pull-requests

Comment: @evolutionxbox PRs that are rebase-merged don't leave such a nice trace in the got log unfortunately.

Comment: I struggle to see how github would know the difference either, but it would be interesting to find out

Comment: @evolutionxbox I'm assuming Github knows the difference on the fact that even for commits that were rebased from a PR, github shows me which PR they originate from when I browse all commits to master. So Github is storing this information somewhere.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a list of pull requests between 2 commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41079634/how-to-get-a-list-of-pull-requests-between-2-commits)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using git CLI, like:

```
git log --grep='Merge pull request' --since='2019-01-01' --until='2020-01-01'
```

where you are searching for merged pull requests between two dates. For this purpose you will need to find out what the dates of the tags are.

The solution above assumes that no rebasing was done during PRs.

On GitHub you can use the UI to search, you may search for PRs between two dates.

Comment: This won't find PRs that have been merged using rebase. Those are "invisible" in pure git, because they look like they have simply been developed on `master`/`main`. Only GitHub itself can have information on those.

Comment: @JoachimSauer thanks for pointing that out. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Note that GitHub also allows to change the names of the merge commit to something argituary

Comment: @dan1st I think that's an edge case. I mean it's a matter of agreed principles to determine how Pull Requests are managed. If this is allowed in a team, then it might restrict the usability of the CLI solution above, so if I may give an advice, I would advice any team to avoid renaming the PR comments.

Answer (score 0):

(This particular answer is based on the [git](/questions/tagged/git) tag, not the [github](/questions/tagged/github) tag.)

It is worth pointing out that the notion of *between* does not always make sense here.  Sometimes it does; consider for instance this series of commits:

```
...--G--H--I--J--K--L--M--N   <-- branch
        ^           ^
        |           |
     tag:v1.0    tag:v1.1
```

The commits "between" the two tags are commits `I-J-K`.  (There's a fencepost issue<sup>1</sup> with deciding whether to include the boundaries at `H` and `L`.)

But: what about this series of commits?

```
          tag:v1.0
             |
             v
          I--J--K   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H
         \
          L--M--N   <-- br2
             ^
             |
          tag:v1.1
```

Which commits, if any, are between these tags?

In any case, Git itself lacks anything like issue trackers, a commenting system, and GitHub-style Pull Requests.  Mapping from these GitHub-specific features into Git must be done at the GitHub end.

---

<sup>1</sup>[The two really hard issues in computing are naming, caching, and fencepost errors.](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html)

Comment: I appreciate this edge case, but in 99% of cases, our team just tags a commit in `master` and deploys that tagged commit to production. I simply want a "changelog" in the format of which new PRs were deployed since the last tag/deploy.